# Generating 3 items per row

Tags: html, css

I am making a website for a school project, I am a noob!

I am one step away from completing the project, the last piece is to get my Dynamically created HTML products to display in a row of 3.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="product-featured-box">

</div>
```

Here is the CSS I have:

```
.product-featured-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
 
.product-box {
  display: flex;
}
```

In the dev view on Google Chrome, the HTML is generated properly, all product-boxes are inside the featured-product-box, but I have no idea how to get the CSS to get it to do what i want!

Any ideas would help!

I a using MAC OS

I tried playing around with the CSS

Comment: Can you add your JavaScript Code / generated HTML?

Comment: In CSS IDs use `#` instead of `.`. So it should be `#product-featured-box { ... }`

Comment: The # worked! Now I just need the proper CSS layout to make sure they all align in 3 :) there are 10 products in total and 3 of those are featured

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be with display: grid. Tell the boxes to display themselves 3 per row of equal width:

```css
#product-featured-box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
}
```

```html
<div id="product-featured-box">
  <div class="product-box">1</div>
  <div class="product-box">2</div>
  <div class="product-box">3</div>
  <div class="product-box">4</div>
  <div class="product-box">5</div>
  <div class="product-box">6</div>
  <div class="product-box">7</div>
  <div class="product-box">8</div>
  <div class="product-box">9</div>
  <div class="product-box">10</div>
</div>
```

`fr` is a unit of proportionality. `1fr` means 1 unit of proportionality, and since you're giving all boxes the same value, they all share the same width.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code it will works for you.

```
<div class="product-featured-box">
<div class="product-box">1</div>
<div class="product-box">2</div>
<div class="product-box">3</div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .product-featured-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

}
 
.product-box {
width: 33.3%;
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
```